# Spring boot - как замапить id строку

Tags: oracle, hibernate

БД перенесена на **Oracle** и все первичные ключи строки. Требуется именно новые значения добавлять. Как правильно маппить?

Ошибка при сохранении такая вылетает.

Все ключи строки. Нет возможности перейти на другой тип только `varchar2`

```
@GenericGenerator
(name = "STRING_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", strategy = "de.kvwl.abrechnung.gostamm.transfer.model.StringSequenceGenerator", parameters = {
@Parameter
(name = "STRING_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", value = "SEQ_GNR") })
@GeneratedValue
(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STRING_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
```

Тип `SequenceStyleGenerator` пытался использовать для маппинга.

Не выходит. **Hibernate** выдает ошибку "неизвестная последовательность".
Как правильно замапить?
Буду благодарен заранее.